# InvokeOperation<bool> value always false

Tags: silverlight, mvvm-light, wcf-ria-services

Quick question about the InvokeOperation, so from my view model i have this...

```
private void IsValidNumber(string value)  
{  
    _context.NumberIsValid(value, ValidNumberCallback, null);  
}   
private void ValidNumberCallback(InvokeOperation<bool> obj)  
{  
    var test = obj.Value; //ALWAYS FALSE????  
}
```

and in my domainSerice class i have this.

```
[Invoke]  
public bool NumberIsValid(string number)  
{  
    return true;  
}
```

and the call back value is always false??? what am I missing???

any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I have used your code verbatim with my test project and it goes off without a hitch.  I will try to think of reason why this would not work for you while at lunch, but honestly there is nothing I can think of off-hand.

Comment: @Matt Greer-Thanks for fixing the format :)

Comment: @Nissan Fan-Yeah its driving me nuts, maybe its something silly like restarting VS2010 :P

Comment: it works well for me too. must be something else.

Comment: if for whatever reason it was returning null would that throw an exception before or in the callback? or would it not even hit the callback method?

Comment: Update: so I changed it from a bool to an int and said to return 5 in my domain service method and in the callback i get 0 
soo bizare :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welp... I decided to just hurry and build a simple test site and it works just peachy... I think it might have to do with something in my webconfig... if I ever find the real issue I'll update this.

```
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
            <remove assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
            <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
            <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
            <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
            <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
            <add assembly="System.Speech, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" /></assemblies>
    </compilation>
```

the assemblies seems to have been the issue, I removed that section and it started working again... why?? no clue

Answer (score 0):

You should check for HasError property.

If for any reason connection to your http server fails, method callback will be called but with HasError as true and you will get details of the error in Error object.

Comment: I have and there is never an error :(

I even added in logging in the webconfig and never get anything